# Clash of clans hero book storage

Tags: clash-of-clans

I currently have a hero book in my clan castle. I am about to complete the golem challenge which will reward me a hero book. What will happen if I complete the challenge with no spot for the book?

Answer (score 1):

If it is completing an event, the book will be added to your clan castle(Town Hall in the new update).
Rewards for events stack so that you can have more than the maximum number!
I currently have 9 power potions; the maximum is 5; 4 were rewards for completing challenges during events

If it is part of a clan game, it will not stack and you will not be able to choose it as a reward.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have those rewards from events as the players have **earned it** by completing event so supercell does not take it away from us. I had 6 training potions and two book of fighting so no need to worry.

Answer (score -1):

Your second will be useless as it is clearly observed that Treasury have only 1 storage place for the Hero Book. So before completing challenge reward, make sure you have empty room for Hero Book.

Comment: Thanks, I though so, but I wondered if it would give me a chance to use it/ sell it or if it would just poofff?!

Comment: Had to downvote because this doesn't clearly answer the OP's question, "What will happen ..."

Comment: Ohh Dear Lord @NickRolando, It clearly says **"Your Second Will Be Useless"**. Don't you read?

Comment: Lol, so you're saying you'll get the 2nd book but it will be useless? That's blatantly false.

Comment: Your answer lacks much detail. Will he be forced to claim the prize immediately, and the extra book goes poof? Or can he choose to claim it at a later time after he uses the one he has? "Your second will be useless" is not only false but vague.

Comment: Yes exactly @NickRolando. It is not from the Clan Games. He asked for the challenge he is about to complete. So it will not ask you as they do in Clan Games "Insufficient Storage to collect the rewards". They will give you the book as soon as you complete the challenge and as there is no sufficient space it will be useless.

Comment: @NickRolando, Yes it is a force give. Those you play Clash of clans already know that rewards from challenge are given immediately and yes forcefully, They don't ask you to collect it by claiming the prize. Those who play COC already know this. I don't need to mention that.

Comment: From the looks of Steve's comment on your answer, that is not the case. I'm sure there are plenty of others who don't know these details as well. I also play and don't know how it works these kinds of rewards. I've only done easy challenges for gems.